# Possible to sequentially run multiple python scripts in the same selenium session?

Tags: python, google-chrome, user-interface, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm taking a shot at UI automation and I was wondering if it was possible to run tests from multiple python scripts in order in the same session?

So for example:

Script 1: Test to Login

Script 2: Test to click button

Script 3: Test to Logout

versus having a single script do all three tests in a single script.

I tried creating a BAT file that will initiate each script one by one, but it will open a new browser window for each execution.

note:
Of course my actual code is much more complex and has many more test cases :) I just want to know if its even possible. Looking it up has been weird. Not sure how to word it out in a way where google would understand lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Python Selenium framework called [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) that can do exactly that.

After `pip install -U seleniumbase`, you can run `pytest --rs` on the following script to reuse the browser session between tests. (There's a special part added at the top to automatically call `pytest` with those args if calling `python` directly):

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "--rs"])

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.open("https://google.com")
        self.sleep(1)

    def test_2(self):
        self.open("https://facebook.com")
        self.sleep(1)

    def test_3(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io")
        self.sleep(1)

    def test_4(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.com")
        self.sleep(1)
```

The `--rs` option will make all tests reuse the same browser session. To access the `driver` that you have via regular `selenium`, use `self.driver`.

Comment: This looks perfect! I'll give it a shot in my code and let you know how it works out :) Thank you!